# Displaying controls in place holder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a multi view with 5 views, in each view i have few controls and a placeholder,next few buttons which fall under these 5 categories of views on first button click i displaying a view and next button click of similar or another category, I taking a `usercontrol` and adding it to the placeholder of the active view in multiview but the problem is while adding to the placeholder i have a situation of adding multiple `usercontrols` to the same placeholder then it is displaying like

If A,B,C,D,E are my user controls
It is displaying like
A
A
A
But i want to display like
AAA

can any1 help me in this context.

Thanks in advance

Comment: suggestion: put code what you tried so far for better solution of your problem.

Comment: Got solution,created a table with a row, inside placeholder and before adding each usercontrol i am creating a dynamic cell each time and adding usercontrol to cell before adding it to the table row thanks @kiran